# Powershell importExcel

Tags: powershell, import

In PowerShell 5.0, I want to install the module importExcel, I wrote :

> Install-Module ImportExcel -scope CurrentUser

A error message appeared :

> Vous installez les modules à partir d'un référentiel non approuvé. Si vous approuvez ce référentiel, modifiez sa valeur
>    InstallationPolicy en exécutant l'applet de commande Set-PSRepository. Voulez-vous vraiment installer les modules à
>   partir de PSGallery ?
>   [O] Oui  [T] Oui pour tout  [N] Non  [U] Non pour tout  [S] Suspendre  [?] Aide (la valeur par défaut est « N ») : O

Comment: I don't read French and I assume you don't either? I'd say powershell is asking if you want to install the module from PSGallery rather than giving you an error. Did you try hitting the O-key and enter?

Comment: I read French and it's written that I want to install a module from a non-approved refential. I tried to press O, but nothing happens after that.

Comment: Ahh, I see. You should try what Ranadip suggested but replace <path> with an actual file path you can save the module to. I'm not entirely sure I got that error right though. Honestly, too much work having to read all that in French and then to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea what path I should write. Can you recommend me one please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like you to save the module locally and then try installing it.

Use this to save it locally:

> Save-Module -Name ImportExcel -Path <path> -RequiredVersion 2.2.7

Then Install it.